# How make pivot table with 2 tables and use Month columns names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Whe have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [FIO] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [HPhone] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [MPhone] [nchar](10) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED )

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payment](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Paid] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
        [date] [date] NULL,
        [IDClient] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Payment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    )
```

How make sql query to build this data:

```
ID  FIO                January   February  March     April     May       etc
--- ------------------ --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
1    Jimm Salvan       200       200       200       200       NULL      etc
2    Bob Dillan        200       200       200       200       NULL      etc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  FIO,
  [1] AS January,
  [2] AS Febrary,
  [3] AS March,
  [4] AS April,
  [5] AS May,
  ... etc
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.FIO,
    ISNULL(p.paid, 0) AS paid,
    MONTH(Date) AS month
  FROM clients AS c
  LEFT JOIN Payment AS p ON c.Id = p.Id
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(paid)
  FOR month IN([1], 
               [2], 
               [3], 
               [4], 
               [5]
               ... etc)
) AS p;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37d26/4)

---

**Edit:** You can use the `DATENAME(MONTH, Date)` to get the month name directly as @AndriyM suggested in the comments below. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.FIO,
    ISNULL(p.paid, 0) AS paid,
    DATENAME(month, Date) AS monthname
  FROM clients AS c
  LEFT JOIN Payment AS p ON c.Id = p.Id
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(paid)
  FOR monthname IN(January, 
                   February,
                   March, 
                   April, 
                   May,
                   ...)
) AS p;
```

[**Like this.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37d26/14)

Comment: Wow Big thanks!!! I just fixed LEFT JOIN Payment AS p ON c.Id = p.IdClent. Thks!!!

Comment: If you use `DATENAME(MONTH, Date)` instead of `MONTH(Date)`, you won't need to rename the numeric column names to month names.

Comment: @AndriyM in a lot of cases they won't sort correctly if you use the names. I'm not sure about this case but you can always apply the friendly labels later (e.g. in the presentation tier).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: You are right. My suggestion was specifically for this case, where month names are supposed to be used merely as column names (as it seems).

Comment: @AndriyM yeah, probably right, just wanted to be clear in case others read peripherally and think using `DATENAME` will still allow sorting.